# if $[\Bbb Q(a,b):\Bbb Q]$ has the same degree as $[\Bbb Q(c):\Bbb Q]$, does $\Bbb Q(a,b)=\Bbb Q(c)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For field extension of the rationals, if $[\Bbb Q(a,b):\Bbb Q]$ has the same degree as $[\Bbb Q(c):\Bbb Q]$, does $\Bbb Q(a,b)=\Bbb Q(c)$?

This was used in my text in the solution to the problem $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2},2^{1/3})=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$. The text claimed that there is inclusion in one direction and because the degree of the extensions are the same, they are in fact equal, which is something I have never heard of before in any theorem relating to fields. I just did this the normal way and showed dual inclusion.

Comment: It is no true in general. $a=\sqrt2,b=\sqrt3, c=\sqrt[4]{5}.$

Comment: But if $F\subseteq E,E’$ and $E$ can be included in $E’,$ and $[E:F]=[E’:F],$ then $E\cong E’.$

Comment: A general advise: Sometimes it makes sense to think of special cases. So what happens if $b=1$? Then $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q}]$ should imply that $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(c)$. This looks rather unlikely. Take $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $c=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Well, you need to also establish that both $a, b$ lie in $\mathbb {Q} (c) $ (or $c$ lies in $\mathbb {Q} (a, b) $). Then tower law can be used to prove that the fields in question are same.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki thank you. Also if [Q(a):Q] and [Q(c):Q] have different degrees, does that then imply that Q(a) cannot be equal to Q(c)?

Comment: The question is missing an obvious condition (as the example of the OP shows): Q(a,b) is contained in Q(c).

Comment: @William Of course. Take the contraposition: If $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ are equal, then they have the same degree.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special fact dependent on the given generators, not a general fact.

We have two fields, $K=\Bbb Q(2^{1/2},2^{1/3})$, and $L=\Bbb Q(2^{1/6})$. If you have an inclusion between them, in either direction, and  know that the degrees are the same, then you can conclude that they are equal.

In fact, however, this is not properly a field-extension degree problem at all. Since $2^{1/6}=2^{1/2}/2^{1/3}$, you have $2^{1/6}\in\Bbb Q(2^{1/2},2^{1/3})$, and thus $L\subset K$.

On the other hand, $2^{1/2}=(2^{1/6})^3$ and $2^{1/3}=(2^{1/6})^2$, so that both are in $\Bbb Q(2^{1/6})$. Thus $K\subset L$, and the fields are equal.

And so I charge the author of your text with poor mathematical writing.

Comment: when you said "If you have an inclusion between them, in either direction, and know that the degrees are the same, then you can conclude that they are equal" , i think I remember something similar in linear algebra as well, but how does the proof go? Proof by contradiction seems easier here. Assume Q(2^1/6) is a proper subset of Q(2^1/2,2^1/3) and that both extensions of degree n. Then there is an element $a$ in Q(2^1/2,2^1/3) that is not in Q(2^1/6). But since the degree is n, the set {1, a, a^2, a^3,....a^n} is linearly dependent.... How should we arrive at the contradiction?

Comment: It depends on the product formula for field extension degrees: If $k\subset K\subset L$, then $[L:k]=[L:K][K:k]$ In your problem, $k=\Bbb Q$. If $[K:k]=[L:k]$, this forces $[L:K]=1$, i.e. $L$ is a one-dimensional vector space over its subfield $K$. Necessarily equal, then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example, take $a = \sqrt2 $ , $b = \sqrt 3$ and $c = \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$.

Proof of the primitive element theorem tells that if $a_i$ and $b_j$ are the conjugates of $a$ and $b$ over rationals then for any $x = a + tb$ we have
$\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(x)$ where $t$ is not of the form $\frac{a_k - a_r}{b_m - b_n}$ where $m \ne n$.

To illustrate this,

If $a = \sqrt 2 $ and $b = \sqrt[3] 2$ then the conjugates of $a$ are $\pm \sqrt 2$ and conjugates of $\sqrt [3] 2$ are $\sqrt[3]2, \omega \sqrt[3]2$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]2$. Also note that $\frac{a_k - a_r}{b_m - b_n}$ is always not a real number because $\omega \sqrt[3]2$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]2$ are complex. So let $t = \frac{\sqrt[6]2 - \sqrt 2}{\sqrt[3]2}$ then you have $x = \sqrt[6]2 = a + tb$ hence $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]2)$